# How can I take an extra percentage fee out of every transaction?

Tags: anchor, rust, javascript

I run a coinflip site built with anchor, and I would like to know how I could take an extra fee out of every transaction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet will be to use the Token-2022 Program. This explains how to set it up so that you can take out transaction fees:

https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees